# How to get rid of org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.util.ExceptionHandler noMessageBodyWriter?

Tags: java, jax-rs, restlet

I can call http://localhost/products and get the desired XML output. If I call http://localhost/facets I get

```
Mar 24, 2015 3:10:50 PM org.restlet.ext.jaxrs.internal.util.ExceptionHandler noMessageBodyWriter
WARNING: No message body writer found for class com.galexis.search.productsearch.bean.facet.FacetsDTO(generic type is class com.galexis.search.productsearch.bean.facet.FacetsDTO); response media type should be: application/xml; accepted media types are: [[text/html, application/xhtml+xml], [application/xml], [*/*]]
```

This is my resource:

```
public class MyResource {

    @Path("products")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public ProductsDTO getProductsByFieldNamesAndSearchStrings(somme parameters) {

        return getProducts();
    }

    @Path("facets")
    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public FacetsDTO getProductsFacetByFieldNamesAndSearchStrings(somme parameters) {
        return getFacets();
    }

}
```

ProductsDTO

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "products")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType
public class ProductsDTO {
   ...
}
```

FacetsDTO

```
@XmlType
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FacetsDTO {
   ...
}
```

Any idea what's missing?

Comment: I can't see any difference between the two DTOs with the content you provided... Could you show us the difference between them? Could you also provide all the dependencies you use for your application? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking the hard tour and debug the restelt jax-rs extenstion I discovered that it checks for a `@XmlRootElement` element. If it's absent it refuses to server an `application/xml` answer.